# Apple Push Notifications in Internal Network

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, vpn

I am trying to implement an enterprise iPad app which consumes web services accessible only through my company internal network through VPN setup.But In order to achieve Apple push notifications i cam to know that it should be public network.

Queries:

1. Is it possible to receive the push notifications over internal VPN setup in ipad just by unblocking the port 5223 (or)
2. Is it mandatory that device should be in public network to receive notifications.

Any suggestions or best alternatives for implementing Apple push notifications over VPN are highly appreciable

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 1):

You'll also need to unblock 2195 to stream your notification requests to Apple, and 2196 for the feedback service.

Comment: Unblocking these port along with 5223 will make APNS work over the VPN ?